# Microseconds print resolution with Log4j2 2.11

Tags: java, spring-boot, timestamp, log4j2

I have the weirdest issue where microseconds time resolution for logging doesn't function properly in some scenarios, while it works fine in others.

Setup description:

- Zulu JDK 11
- Gradle 5.1.1 project
- Log4j2 2.11.1 dependencies.
- Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE application

Here's the Log4j2 XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="ERROR" shutdownHook="disable">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,nnnnnn} [%t] %level{length=5} %c{1} -%equals{ |%marker|}{ ||}{} %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When I run this setup manually via `./gradlew clean bootRun` I get perfect *us* resolution.

However, when I package the files into a **"fat"** spring boot jar (via `./gradlew clean bootJar` and then run it, I get only milliseconds level fractions of a second.

Of course the log4j2.xml file is properly packaged as part of the spring boot jar.

I'm guessing it's somehow related to classpath issues, but for the love of god, I cannot understand what's causing this behavior.

Any help/suggestions will be much advised.

Comment: I agree that is strange. When you set `status = “TRACE”` in the configuration, log4j will print its internal logging to the console. Can you share what you see in both cases?

Comment: I think I'm on to something. Will update prompetly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Even though @rgoers was technically right in his observation, adding the multi-release flag to the manifest did *not* resolve the issue. It turned out this was a spring boot 2 issue in the workings, now resolved with Spring boot 2.1.2 (perhaps even on 2.1.1).

Logging now behaves properly without altering the manifest.

Additional info can be found in here - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12523

Answer (score 1):

The Log4j API and Implementation jars are packaged as multi-release jars. In their infinite wisdom, the JDK designers ignore that if you package the jars inside another jar that doesn't have the multi-release: true manifest header. Without that you will not be executing any of the Java 9+ support built into Log4j.

The bottom line is - add the multi-release: true header to the Spring Boot application jar manifest.

Comment: Yep, already figured it out. Never had time to write it as an answer.
Anyways - you are correct. Thanks :)
 
Also, I think that these classes have moved, and that it'd be different from the upcoming release.

Comment: this turned out to be  a spring-boot  issue. altering the manifest did not help. 10x anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Following [log4j documentation](https://blogs.apache.org/logging/entry/log4j-2-11-released)

> One 2.11 feature worth highlighting is that log timestamps can now have microsecond or nanosecond precision when running on Java 9.

Are you sure, what your app is running under the same JRE in both cases?

Comment: Positive. Besides, the app is compiled for `sourceCompatibility = 1.11` , so it wouldn't run were the situation different.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer.